# How to integrate Mule esb with Hawtio monitoring

Tags: mule, jmx, mule-component, hawtio, jolokia

I have integrated Mule ESB with Hawtio as per the below link and it is working fine.

https://www.ivankrizsan.se/2014/08/24/remote-jmx-monitoring-of-a-mule-instance/

Is there any way to start/stop the mule applications from Hawtio as like tomcat working in Hawtio. I know that Tomcat, Fuse had hawtio plug-in to providing this solution but want to know whether this can be done for Mule.

Correct me if my understanding is wrong.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the hawtio point of view, it depends on whether Mule ESB provides a MBean that has start/stop operations. If it does, you can just find the MBean in the JMX tree and invoke the operations from the hawtio JMX tab.

If you are looking for a more sophisticated integration with Mule ESB, then you would need to write a custom hawtio plugin. See these resources for more info:

- http://hawtio.github.io/hawtio/plugins/howPluginsWork.html
- https://github.com/hawtio/hawtio/tree/hawtio-1.5.0/hawtio-plugin-examples/simple-plugin